# Allow another computer or mobile to access apache web server on PC(Win 7) through internet?

Tags: remote-access, self-hosting

I downloaded and installed WAMPSERVER which is running perfectly.

Now, I want to access it using my mobile.

I went through these steps : http://dyn.com/support/wizard-js/#website

1. WAMP Server running and online
2. [open port 80](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/), done
3. No router
4. Don't know about bridging modems. I'm using my mobile phone as a modem(Samsung, Android 2.3.6, AirTel)

www.canyouseeme.org says *"Error: I could not see your service on xxx.xxx.x.xxx(my public ip address, of course) on port (80) Reason: Connection refused"*

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions on dyn.com are based on a typical home DSL/Cable broadband situation. Are you saying that you're not using typical home broadband, and instead your WAMP server machine gets on the Internet via your Android phone?

Does your WAMP server get a publicly routable IPv4 address, or does it get an RFC 1918 private address (192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x, 172.[16-31].x.x)? If it gets a private address, then your Android phone is probably acting as a NAT gateway. You'll need to set up the port mapping (a.k.a. port forwarding) in Android's NAT software. You'll also need to make sure that Android isn't running a firewall blocking port 80, and that Android doesn't have any processes running that may be using port 80 for themselves.

If it still doesn't work, then you may have to see if your wireless carrier blocks connections to port 80.

Comment: Don't forget that typically mobile network operators also use NAT-gateways, in that case you will never reach port 80 from the Internet.

Comment: Yes, I connect to internet via my android phone. My WAMP server(or computer it is on) has dynamic public ip address 223.184.xxx.xx